# R, ggplot2 shapes in unicode

Tags: r, macos, unicode, ms-word, character-encoding

I've used ggplot2 shapes in my plots, and now need to find the shapes in order to use them in word.

Where do ggplot2 pch shapes come from?

**I am specifically looking for #9, "diamond plus".**

I've looked through many unicode charts, and tried searching, but cannot find this character. How can I insert it into word?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use "shape" to set a unicode character:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = "\u2020", size = 3)
```

You have to note that the final result will depend on the font used to generate the plot. I used a cross as you see.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but you've misunderstood - I've created a plot using shape=9, and am now trying to find a solution so that I can type the shapes I used in my plot caption in word.

Comment: Wait, you mean that you want that diamond shape character in Microsoft Word? What operating systems do you use: Windows or Mac or Linux?

Comment: Yep! That's what I want to do. I use Mac.

Comment: Ok, that Symbol is not in the character map on Mac. However you have a similar one, go to the top menu bar on Mac and choose edit> Emoji & Symbols. You'll see a window with Smileys & People, just click on the top right corner icon. Then go to bullets/Stars and select for example the white diamond `◇ WHITE DIAMOND Unicode: U+25C7, UTF-8: E2 97 87` you can use that symbol in word. By the way this example runs on Mojave. Hope this helps.